# CMake Error: 'iDynTree::idyntree-core' was not found before

Tags: ros2, cmake, foxy

I am trying to build my package ros2_control_demo_hardware which uses ros2 control. But I have the following error after `colcon build`:

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/foxy/share/ament_cmake_target_dependencies/cmake/ament_target_dependencies.cmake:77 (message):
  ament_target_dependencies() the passed package name
  'iDynTree::idyntree-core' was not found before
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:124 (ament_target_dependencies)
```

I realised when I comment only the line 124 then the build process will finish.
I also tried to install idyntree-core with `sudo apt-get install ros-foxy-idyntree-core` but it didn't exist.
Also adding `find_package(iDynTree_core REQUIRED)` didn't solve the problem.

Here is my CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(ros2_control_demo_hardware)

# Default to C++14
if(NOT CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
endif()

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
  add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra)
endif()

# ROS 2 specific
find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
find_package(ros2_common_utilities REQUIRED)
find_package(controller_interface REQUIRED)
find_package(controller_manager REQUIRED)
find_package(effort_controllers REQUIRED)
find_package(geometry_msgs REQUIRED)
find_package(hardware_interface REQUIRED)
find_package(pluginlib REQUIRED)
find_package(rclcpp REQUIRED)
find_package(robot_state_publisher REQUIRED)
find_package(roboy_middleware_msgs REQUIRED)
find_package(roboy_simulation_msgs REQUIRED)
find_package(roboy_control_msgs REQUIRED)
find_package(std_msgs REQUIRED)
find_package(tf2 REQUIRED)
find_package(tf2_geometry_msgs REQUIRED)
find_package(tf2_ros REQUIRED)

# Eigen
find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIRS})

# # libxml++
# find_package(LibXML++ REQUIRED)
# include_directories(${LibXML++_INCLUDE_DIRS})

# idyntree ################# find package exist here ##################
find_package(iDynTree 0.11.1 REQUIRED)            
include_directories(${iDynTree_INCLUDE_DIRS})

# qpOASES
find_package(qpOASES REQUIRED)
include_directories(${qpOASES_INCLUDE_DIRS})

# find openmp support
find_package(OpenMP)
if (OPENMP_FOUND)
  set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_C_FLAGS}")
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS}")
  set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS}")
endif()

# Include directories
include_directories(
    include/
    ${ament_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

# # Generate ROS 2 interfaces
# rosidl_generate_interfaces(${PROJECT_NAME}
#     "msg/YourCustomMessage.msg"
#     "srv/YourCustomService.srv"
#     DEPENDENCIES std_msgs geometry_msgs message_generation ros2_common_utilities roboy_middleware_msgs roboy_simulation_msgs roboy_control_msgs
# )


# Define targets
# CARDSflow hardware interface
add_library(
  CardsflowHardwareInterface
  src/controller/cardsflow_state_interface.cpp
  src/controller/cardsflow_command_interface.cpp
)
ament_target_dependencies(
  CardsflowHardwareInterface
  roboy_middleware_msgs
  ros2_common_utilities
)


# Cable Length Controller
add_library(
  CableLengthController
  src/cableLengthController.cpp
)
ament_target_dependencies(
  CableLengthController
  roboy_middleware_msgs
  roboy_control_msgs
  controller_interface            
  hardware_interface              
  pluginlib                       
  rclcpp                          
  rcpputils
  # CardsflowHardwareInterface
)
target_include_directories(       
  CableLengthController PRIVATE   
  ${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIRS}          
  include                         
)
target_link_libraries(
  CableLengthController
  # ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
  CardsflowHardwareInterface
)


# ros2_control_demo_hardware library
add_library(
  ros2_control_demo_hardware SHARED
  
  src/EigenExtension.cpp
  src/rrbot_system_position_only.cpp # src/robot.cpp
    src/kinematics.cpp
    include/ros2_control_demo_hardware/EigenExtension.hpp
    include/ros2_control_demo_hardware/rrbot_system_position_only.hpp # include/ros2_control_demo_hardware/robot.hpp
    include/ros2_control_demo_hardware/kinematics.hpp
    include/ros2_control_demo_hardware/cable.hpp
)
ament_target_dependencies(
  ros2_control_demo_hardware
  roboy_simulation_msgs
  ${ament_LIBRARIES}
  ${iDynTree_LIBRARIES} ############# line 124 ############## 
  ${qpOASES_LIBRARIES}
  hardware_interface                
  pluginlib                         
  rclcpp                            
  ${OpenMP_CXX_libraries}
)
target_include_directories(         
  ros2_control_demo_hardware        
  PUBLIC                                                                        
  $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/ros2_control_demo_hardware/include>   
  $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include/ros2_control_demo_hardware>                       
  PRIVATE                           
  ${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIRS}            
  include                           
)
target_link_libraries(
  ros2_control_demo_hardware
  # ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
  CardsflowHardwareInterface
  CableLengthController
)

# What is this??? 
# Export hardware plugins
pluginlib_export_plugin_description_file(hardware_interface ros2_control_demo_hardware.xml)
# Export controller plugins
pluginlib_export_plugin_description_file(controller_interface ros2_control_demo_hardware.xml)


# Install targets
install(TARGETS
    CardsflowHardwareInterface
    CableLengthController
    ros2_control_demo_hardware
    LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
    RUNTIME DESTINATION lib/${PROJECT_NAME}
)

install(                  
  DIRECTORY include/      
  DESTINATION include     
)

# Install other files
install(FILES
    package.xml
    CableLengthController_plugin.xml
    DESTINATION share/${PROJECT_NAME}
)

# Install include files
install(DIRECTORY
    include/ros2_control_demo_hardware/
    include/ros2_control_demo_hardware/controller
    DESTINATION include/${PROJECT_NAME}
    FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.hpp"
)

# EXPORTS
ament_export_include_directories(               
  include                                       
)
ament_export_libraries(                         
  CardsflowHardwareInterface                   
  CableLengthController                         
  ros2_control_demo_hardware # ${PROJECT_NAME}  
)
ament_export_dependencies(                     
  hardware_interface                            
  pluginlib
  rclcpp
)


ament_package()
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to install iDynTree properly:
https://docs.conda.io/projects/miniconda/en/latest/